# Mounting files of another VPS

Tags: linux, mount, ftp, webserver, file-sharing

So I'm not quite sure how to phrase this, which I'm sure is the reason I haven't found the answer on Google.

But basically I've got two servers.

1. Runs webserver (apache, mysql, ..)
2. Fileserver (hosts files for that website)

The webserver will need to manage files on the fileserver.

Now my question is: What is the best way to manage files on this other server?

Is there a way to directly mount a directory from another server?

My best guess right now is to just do it through FTP but it seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the level of control, but a generally accepted method is to use NFS. NFS is designed to directly mount a directory from a remote server.

Another possibility which is simpler and more secure might be to use sshfs- which would do something similar to NFS, but with encryption and less clean semantics.

At a push you could use an SMB (windows fileshare mount)

FTP is not a great candidate as it's a horrible, messy, insecure protocol, and I would not trust it where I have control of the sharing mechanism.

Comment: I'd say FTP is not any less secure than SMB, only worse from the design perspective...

Comment: @grawity Yes, we largely agree - both FTP and SMB suck.   Technically, I think SMB should be considered nominally more secure because SAMBA offers encryption (smb encrypt) - of-course, you could throw Wannacry/CVE-2017-7494 back in my face. Then again, SMB directory sharing is a lot more prevalent then curlftpfs.

Comment: Yes, SMBv3 has native encryption support, but FTP has had TLS (FTPS) support for many years as well.

Answer (score 0):

> The webserver will need to manage files on the fileserver.

That's a very vague notion. If you mean "files uploaded will need to be stored on the file server" then aside from the network filesystems above I might think of [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd) and slap a webserver on the file server as well, probably nginx. There are a number of useful scenarios here:

1. It can be on a private VLAN, serving files only via the app
2. It can be public but severely restricted like [rate limiting](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html), [GeoIP limiting](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access-geoip/) and so forth.
3. There can be several copies or shards of your files and then scalability, high availability are possibilities even with the app down.